# CSS - Como faço esse efeito na div deste site

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Galera,

No link abaixo, a parte de cima do site, ou seja, o cabeçalho que é a foto de fundo junto com o menu, eles ocupam a tela toda do browser, indifernete de ser pc, tablet ou smartphone, como faço para aplicar este efeito?

https://www.templatemonster.com/pt-br/demo/61143.html

Comment: sua duvida não esta clara o suficiente, pode melhora-la?

Comment: ajustado @RafaelAcioly

Comment: Como sua dúvida não abrange diretamente um trecho de código, mas sim de como fazer, comece lendo a [documentação](http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/) da API utilizada no site. Tente reproduzir o efeito que você deseja e, caso não consiga, volte aqui com seu código.

Comment: Tem como reproduzir este efeito com css puro ou bootstrap?

Comment: Descreva na pergunta detalhadamente o efeito, para que fique claro o que quer sem que tenhamos que abrir o link externo e tentar adivinhar. Isso aumentaria muito a chance de uma resposta adequada, ou mesmo da indicação de uma resposta já existente com a solução.

Comment: Se a dúvida é só a imagem em "tela cheia", já tem a solução aqui: [Colocar uma imagem de background e deixa-la responsiva](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87402/colocar-uma-imagem-de-background-e-deixa-la-responsiva)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eis o que eu queria

```css
* {margin:0; padding: 0;}
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
.header {
    width:100%; 
    height:auto; 
    min-height:100%; 
    /* 
    aqui é onde acontece a mágica, 
    a propriedade height:auto e min-height: 100% 
    fará com que esta div ocupe sempre a altura total 
    do navegador, mesmo quando redimensionado 
    */
    background:cornflowerblue;
}
```

Creditos: http://www.blog.andrerubiodesign.com.br/2013/10/div-ocupando-toda-altura-de-uma-pagina.html

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma `<div>`, por exemplo `<div class="barra-topo">` com o conteúdo: background, botões, campos e etc. No **CSS** do background use `widht: 100%;` para que o fundo preencha toda a extensão da tela.

Você terá que criar as viewports para que se alterem de acordo com o aparelho. Veja que o modelo da barra é a mesma, porém o conteúdo se altera. Pesquise por CSS media queries.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não só no comprimento, mais no height também! me entende?